# How do I set a column to the number that was generated by MySQL for a previously set row?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, sql-delete

So, I created an INSERT statement on MySQL that added a certain row to a table. The invoice_id was set to DEFAULT. Now, I need to find out what that auto-generated id was to continue. How do I go about that?

I've tried using DEFAULT and AUTO to see if they would do the trick. They did not.

```
    INSERT into ap.terms 
VALUES (terms_id = 6, terms_description = 'Net due 120 days', terms_due_days = 120);

UPDATE ap.terms 
SET terms_description = 'Net due 125 days', terms_due_days = 125
WHERE terms_id = 6;

DELETE FROM ap.terms
WHERE terms_id = 6;

INSERT into ap.invoices
VALUES (AUTO_INCREMENT, 32, 'AX-014-027', '2014-08-01', '434.58', '0.00', '0.00', 2, '2014-08-31', NULL);

INSERT into ap.invoice_line_items
VALUES (invoice_sequence = 1, account_number = 160, line_item_amount = '180.23', line_item_description = 'Hard drive'), (invoice_sequence = 2, account_number = 527, line_item_amount = '254.35', line_item_description = 'Exchange Server update')
SET invoice_id = last_insert_id(1,1);

UPDATE ap.invoices
SET credit_total = invoice_total*0.1, invoice_total = (payment_total + credit_total)
WHERE invoice_number = 'AX-014-027';  

UPDATE ap.vendors
SET default_account_number = 403
WHERE vendor_id = 44;

UPDATE ap.invoices
SET terms_id = 2
WHERE default_terms_id = 2;

DELETE FROM ap.invoice_line_items
WHERE invoice_id = last_insert_id(1,1);

DELETE FROM ap.invoices
WHERE invoice_id = last_insert_id(1,1);
```

So, line 16, where it says "SET invoice_id = last_insert_id(1,1)" is where my Error is. How do I fix it?

> Error code 1062, you have an error in your sql syntax. Check the manual that corresponds.

Comment: Please show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is incorrect. Your primary key should be set to auto increment, default none. You should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the last row ID inserted into the database.